# Checking conditions before allowing a play button to become visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code to check a couple conditions before allowing a <kbd>play</kbd> button to become visible. Is there anything to do to consolidate this code?

```
var isNodeWebkit = (typeof process == "object"); // check if using node app
var downloadURL = 'https://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/get-started/install/'; // setup download URL variable
var isEncoding = false; // setup isEncoding variable

if (!Silverlight.isInstalled("1.0")) { // check if silverlight is installed
    $('.playbtn').hide();
    $('.videoposter').append('<button class="installbtn" />');
    if (isNodeWebkit) {
        $('.installbtn').on('click', function () { // open silverlight download externally
            require('nw.gui').Shell.openExternal(downloadURL);
            var win = require('nw.gui').Window.get();
            win.close(); return false;
        });
    } else {
        $('.installbtn').click(function () { // open silverlight download in new tab
            window.open(downloadURL, '_blank');
        });
        $(window).focus(function () {
            if (Silverlight.isInstalled("1.0")) {
                $('.installbtn').remove();
                $('.playbtn').show(); checkEncodingFunc();
            } else if (!Silverlight.isInstalled("1.0")) {
                $('.installbtn').remove(); $('.videoposter').append('<button class="installbtn" />');
                $('.playbtn').hide(); $('.encodingbtn').hide();
            }; ;
        });
    };
} else if (Silverlight.isInstalled("1.0")) {
    $(window).focus(function () { // after installing show play button
        if (!Silverlight.isInstalled("1.0")) {
            $('.playbtn').hide(); $('.installbtn').remove(); $('.encodingbtn').remove();
            $('.videoposter').append('<button class="installbtn" />');
            $('.installbtn').click(function () { // open silverlight download in new tab
                window.open(downloadURL, '_blank');
            });
        } else {
            $('.installbtn').remove();
            $('.playbtn').show();
        };
        if (Silverlight.isInstalled("1.0") && isEncoding == true) { checkEncodingFunc(); };
    });
};

var encodeTimer = setInterval(function () { if (isEncoding == true) { checkEncodingFunc(); }; }, 60000);
if (Silverlight.isInstalled("1.0")) { checkEncodingFunc(); };

function checkEncodingFunc() { // check if video is encoding
    $.ajax({
        url: 'video/',
        statusCode: {
            200: function () { // if video is found display play button
                if (isEncoding == true) {
                    $('.encodingbtn').remove();
                    $('.playbtn').show();
                    isEncoding = false;
                };
            },
            204: function () { // if video is encoding display encoding button
                if (Silverlight.isInstalled("1.0")) {
                    isEncoding = true;
                    $('.playbtn').hide(); $('.encodingbtn').remove();
                    $('.videoposter').append('<button class="encodingbtn" />');
                };
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just a few more minor things on top of [jt0dd](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/44716/jt0dd)'s excellent review.

---

Anonymous functions in JavaScript are awesome, but your program will be more readable if you give the main functions names and declare in advance. That way the main part of your program will become something like this:

```
if (!haveSilverlight) {
    $('.playbtn').hide();
    $('.videoposter').append('<button class="installbtn" />');
    if (isNodeWebkit) {
        $('.installbtn').on('click', openExternalSilverlightDownloader);
    } else {
        $('.installbtn').on('click', openSilverlightDownloader);
        $(window).on('focus', setupInstallBtn);
    }
} else {
    $(window).on('focus', setupPlayBtn);
}
```

Easier to see the overall logic, no?

---

Don't write `if` statements this way:

> ```
> if (something) {
>      // ...
> } else if (!something) {
>      // ...
> }
> ```

That's what `else` is for:

```
if (something) {
     // ...
} else {
     // ...
}
```

---

You don't need to evaluate boolean variables like this:

> ```
> if (isEncoding == true) {
>     // ...
> }
> ```

You can do simply:

```
if (isEncoding) {
    // ...
}
```

---

On this line, you don't need the brackets, and I think the code would be more readable with the comment on the line before the assignment.

> ```
> var isNodeWebkit = (typeof process == "object"); // check if using node app
> ```

Better this way:

```
// check if using node app
var isNodeWebkit = typeof process == "object";
```

---

Especially with long lines like this, definitely don't put comment after the statement, as it forces me to scroll right, which is not convenient. Even better, the a comment saying `// setup download URL variable` for a variable assignment is pointless, so it's better to just drop it.

> ```
> var downloadURL = 'https://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/get-started/install/'; // setup download URL variable
> var isEncoding = false; // setup isEncoding variable
> ```

These lines should have been just:

```
var downloadURL = 'https://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/get-started/install/';
var isEncoding = false;
```

Without comments, assignments are self-explanatory.

Comment: Very good. [Teamwork review](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2106/jack-of-all-trades-master-of-none-lets-work-together-to-offer-ultimately-bet) +1!

Comment: I'd +2 if I could for the last note. Code that scrolls off-screen drives my OCD wild.

Answer (score 14):

### Ok first of all.. Silverlight Rant.

Silverlight was <s>a flop</s> far less successful than Microsoft expected it to be. HTML5 + WebGL, on the other hand, is the future of handling anything that anyone ever thought Silverlight might do. If you want to maintain highly supported, future-proof practices, start doing some WebGL research. [It's INCREDIBLE.](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_bumpmap_skin) Silverlight is another one of Microsoft's attempts to avoid standardization and control the web with their own tech. They've failed every single time so far.

Lesson: Avoid Microsoft's proprietary stuff when possible.

### Now, for a Review on Practices..

As far as your code formatting and practices go, I'm happy with what I see. There are a few improvements you can make to make your code a bit simpler:

You use `if(!Silverlight.isInstalled("1.0")) // do stuff` all over the place. Try this instead:

```
var silverlightCheck = Silverlight.isInstalled("1.0");
if (silverlightcheck) // do stuff
```

I saw these on the same line: `$('.playbtn').show(); checkEncodingFunc();` Nu uh. Nope. Use:

```
$('.playbtn').show(); 
checkEncodingFunc();
```

And one more simplification:

You can make selectors that you often repeat, such as `$('.installbtn')` into variables.

```
 var installButton = $('.installbtn'); //
```

That way, you type that selector a little quicker via the variable.

I've touched on some simplification. Someone might review this to contribute improvement to the structure, but **this is not bad code.** +1 for you!

Comment: Yeah silverlight is so bad its used by almost every major streaming service ever

Comment: @AshleyMedway That's ironic. [Have a read](http://gizmodo.com/5994732/streaming-movies-on-netflix-might-suck-less-soon-thanks-to-html5). Silverlight is *dying*; All of the major streaming services ever are running away from it *fast*.

Comment: thats not irony...

Comment: A note about Silverlight: if you need to support older versions of Internet Explorer, you don't have the full power of HTML5 available. WebGL is only fully supported in IE11, and not everyone who uses older versions of IE has switched yet. Especially corporate networks and governments are likely to be on older versions of IE.

Comment: IE11 is the most recent version of IE and, at least on my machine, scores better on the ACID3 test than Chrome. It's still nowhere near as good as Chrome or Firefox (mainly due to the lack of 3rd party plugin support), but it's not a deadly sin to still have to use it. It's the older versions, like IE8 thorugh 10, that should be a capital offense. And a lot of companies have legacy apps designed for older browsers that don't work all that well with more recent browsers.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Ooops. I automatically thought: **he's talking about legacy IE versions** *without even reading.* Assumed it was another "We must support IE7!". My mistake there xD

Comment: @jt0dd for IE support, I would say that the oldest version to support would be IE9. it's the first one that started to support the actual standards. If your customer wants you to support older versions of IE, try your best to make him pay extra for it.

Comment: This answer is [referenced on meta](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2110/are-rants-valid-in-an-answer).